# What would cause this kind of screen corruption?

Tags: linux, memory, video, graphics-card

Today I experienced a weird kind of screen corruption on my system: a rectangular block of pixels on my desktop started jittering in and out of place. I.e. it sometimes displays the "normal" pixels and sometimes part of a different window. Here's a close-up:

[image: Blocks flashing in and out of place]

The jittering happens rapidly (several times a second), semi-randomly but seems tied to paint events, i.e. it now flashes on and off while I'm typing. The pattern sometimes changes; opening or closing a window may stop it temporarely or change the contents and/or block pattern.

I measured the coordinates; the top-left corner is (384, 256) and the block size is 128x128 pixels; nice round power-of-2 figures.

I've seen something similar before but in a smaller region, mainly while playing Minecraft (which is quite video memory hungry). This is the first time it affects the desktop itself.

So the main question is: what's broken here? I assume it's a memory problem, but where? What is more likely, video RAM or main system RAM (I haven't experienced stability issues with the system sofar).

- OS: ArchLinux,
- CPU: Intel Core2 Quad CPU (Q8300)
- GPU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Tahiti XT [Radeon HD 7970/8970 OEM / R9 280X], card made by MSI
- Video drivers: radeon, amdgpu

Comment: "opening or closing a window may stop it" for a second there i thought you had a really, really weird issue. "it only happens if i leave the door ajar !"

Comment: @zx485 That picture was a screengrab, not a photo so it's definetely not in the monitor. So it actually shows up in the graphics output buffer.

Comment: Video RAM is most likely, but given that the contents of the whitish blocks looks feasibly from other areas in memory (the arrow and so on) it could be an intermittent solder connection between the GPU chip itself and attached memory letting an address bit change and memory feeding back data from a different location. Only a guess, hence a comment.

Comment: Swap the ram (or remove 1, or all but 1 stick), see what happens. Swap the video card, see what happens. And is software up to date? Or maybe a new (bad) video driver or kernel just got installed? Are the vents clean & fans spinning normally, anything overheating, check temps?